# ArrayList estatico retorna size 0 quando tento recupera-lo em um activity

Tags: java, android, static

Tenho Esta classe:

```
abstract public class ListaEstaticaDeErros {
private static ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> listErros = new ArrayList<DescritorDeErro>();
private static boolean fimSinc = false;
private static int municipio = 0;

public static boolean getFimSinc(){
    return fimSinc;
}

public static int getMunicipio(){
    return municipio;
}

public static void setMunicipio(int i){
    municipio = i;
}

public static void setFimSinc(boolean b){
    fimSinc = b;
}

public static void setListErros(ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> list){
    listErros = list;
}

public static void addRegListErros(DescritorDeErro obj){
    listErros.add(obj);
}

public static ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> getListErros(){
    return listErros;
}

}
```

Activity função que tento recuperar e mostrar o tamanho da lista:

```
public void montarResultados(){
        Log.e("Teste-esus", String.valueOf(ListaEstaticaDeErros.getListErros().size()));
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> lst = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("lista");
        int mun = bundle.getInt("municipio");
        String usuario = bundle.getString("usuario");
        if(lst.size() > 0) {
            new ChargeList().execute(lst, mun, usuario);
        }else{
            txtVInfo.setText("Nenhum erro capturado ate este momento de sincronização.");
        }
        if(bundle.getBoolean("fim_sinc")) {
            txtEmail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            txtEmail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

E dentro de uma activity eu preciso recuperar essa listErros e ela sempre me retorna 0, ou seja sem nenhum elemento, porem se eu pegar ela em outra classe que não seja uma activity eu consigo sem problemas, então a solução que fiz foi pegar ela em outra classe e enviar via intent para a activity que preciso, porem eu gostaria de pega-la diretamente da activity para poder implementar o que preciso.

Comment: Pode adicionar o código da Activity que acessa a lista?

Comment: Adicionei a função

Answer (score 0):

Pode Fazer assim:

```
    public class ListaEstaticaDeErros {
    private ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> listErros = new ArrayList<DescritorDeErro>();
    private boolean fimSinc = false;
    private int municipio = 0;

    private static ListaEstaticaDeErros instance;

    public static ListaEstaticaDeErros getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ListaEstaticaDeErros()
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public  boolean getFimSinc(){
        retmSinc;
    }

    public  int getMunicipio(){
        retnicipio;
    }

    public  void setMunicipio(int i){
        mun = i;
    }

    public  void setFimSinc(boolean b){
        fim b;
    }

    public  void setListErros(ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> list){
        lis = list;
    }

    public  void addRegListErros(DescritorDeErro obj){
        lis.add(obj);
    }

    public  ArrayList<DescritorDeErro> getListErros(){
        return listErros;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ja fiz desta forma tb e nada, foi o jeito q fiz antes do q esta na pergunta.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos porque é que a tua class é abstract?

Comment: Eu tentei varais formas que encontrei pela internet, uma foi igual a sua resposta, me retornou o mesmo resultado que a classe abstract, mas em suma não tem motivo para ser abstract.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma interface como abaixo, que irá conseguir recuperar os valores do listErros.

public interface ListaEstaticaDeErros {

static ArrayList listErros = new ArrayList();

...
}

Comment: Não funciona, alem de continuar não conseguindo enxergar o conteudo da lista, as variaveis de uma interface são "final" e sendo assim não consigo modificar nenhuma delas.